# Trying to define an index within Elasticsearch for py-image-dedup

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get py-image-dedup working (https://github.com/markusressel/py-image-dedup) which requires an index built within elasticsearch.   So far so good,  all python code for py-image-dedup working and brew install elasticsearch all installed and working with the elasticsearch server happily working at local host address 127.0.0.1:9200

So now I try to build the index.    The instructions say

```
curl -X PUT "127.0.0.1:9200/images?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "
{
  \"mappings\": {
    \"image\": {
      \"properties\": {
        \"path\": {
          \"type\": \"keyword\",
          \"ignore_above\": 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which is clearly missing a " at the end and doesn't work in any variant as far as I can see.

I try

```
curl -X PUT "127.0.0.1:9200/images?pretty"  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"mappings\":{\"image\":{\"properties\":{\"path\":{\"type\":\"keyword\",\"ignore_above\":256}}}}} "
```

which looks sensible but get

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [image : {properties={path={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [image : {properties={path={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [image : {properties={path={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

and cannot for the life of me see why the index is not building correctly.  Grateful for help.

Comment: what version of Elasticsearch you are using?

Comment: @glenacota  Version: 7.6.0, Build: default/tar/7f634e9f44834fbc12724506cc1da681b0c3b1e3/2020-02-06T00:09:00.449973Z, JVM: 13.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to use types, which have been deprecated: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html

Please drop the `image` type from your mapping definition.

```
curl -X PUT "127.0.0.1:9200/images?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "
{
  \"mappings\": {
    \"properties\": {
      \"path\": {
        \"type\": \"keyword\",
        \"ignore_above\": 256
      }
    }
  }
}
```